# Salesforce CPQ - Managed Extension Package - Expiration Date

Tags: managed-package, cpq, managed-extension

I am looking to create a managed extension package for Salesforce CPQ. In particular, I would like to add some custom fields to the managed Quote object `SBQQ__Quote__c`. For example, if my package has namespace `ExtNS`, I would want to add some fields like this:

- `SBQQ__Quote__c.ExtNS__CustomFieldA__c`
- `SBQQ__Quote__c.ExtNS__CustomFieldB__c`
- `SBQQ__Quote__c.ExtNS__CustomFieldC__c`

In order to see the `SBQQ__Quote__c` object in a development org, I need to install the Salesforce CPQ managed package. This package unfortunately installs with an expiration date.

[image: SBQQ Expiration Date]

Once my managed extension package is published, the custom fields on the `SBQQ__Quote__c` object that I have added will be locked and there will be no way to remove them. The Salesforce CPQ managed package will eventually expire as well, at which point I will be stuck.

Ideally, I would like to install the Salesforce CPQ into a development org without an expiration date on the package. Is this possible? If not, how would I deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a support case in the Salesforce Partner Portal. They were able to activate the package for a year. I am assuming that they will extend the license next year as long as we continue to be a partner in good standing.